# Repeat rows N of times based on a given if condition in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

So I have a column that contains the following rows

```
7-A
9-B
10-C
```

What I want to do is "If the first digit from left is 7 repeat 6 times, if the first digit from left is 9 repeat 8 times, if 10 repeat 9 times,"

I was able to do that with the below formula however it only works with one repetition setting

```
=sort(trim(transpose(split(query(arrayformula(REPT(A2:A600&"*",6)),,9999),"*"))),1,0)
```

But I need to change the repetition based on the mentioned condition

If there's a way to do it with script editor that would be also great

Appreciate it

Comment: What's the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(FLATTEN(IFNA(SPLIT(REPT(IF(A2:A="",,A2:A&"♀"), 
 REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "\d+")-1), "♀"))), "where Col1 is not null", 0))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(FLATTEN(IFNA(SPLIT(REPT(IF(A2:A="",,A2:A&"♀"), 
 VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "\d+")*1, 
 {5, 6; 6, 6; 7, 6; 8, 6; 9, 8; 10, 9; 11, 9}, 2, 0)), "♀"))), 
 "where Col1 is not NULL", 0))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you it does the job,  I would appreciate some explanation please. 

I have also done it with the below
`=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",",IFERROR(REPT(A1:A900&",",B1:B900))),",")))`

Comment: Oh, My bad I think there is a miss understanding,  I Also need if 5-A, 6-A, 8-A to repeat 6 times 

11-A and 10-A to repeat 9 times.

Im unable to edit the Question description.

Answer (score 2):

The `REPT` can take a matching array of arguments. To your code, add a variable second argument using regexextract

```
=sort(trim(transpose(split(query(arrayformula(REPT(A1:A3&"*",REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A3,"\d+")-1)),,9999),"*"))),1,0)
```